# Method Chaining and the new Keyword returning error in PHP 5.4.x

Tags: php

I was trying to chain the following code below into 1 line. Purely for experimentation to see if it could be done.

This is the original code, which works:

```
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHtml($html);
$xpath = new DomXPath($dom);
```

But, when chaining, this returns an error:

```
$xpath = new DomXPath((new DomDocument())->loadHtml($html));
```

The error is:

```
Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to DOMXPath::__construct() must be an instance of DOMDocument, boolean given
```

If this sort of chaining is allowed in PHP 5.4.x the why does it not work as expected?

Comment: It's allowed if the classes support ie (IE: methods return `$this`)

Comment: You could try: `$xpath = new DomXPath(DomDocument::loadHtml($html));`

Comment: You can't call loadHtml statically.

Comment: That's a scope resolution operator. You can use it: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/73f-fr2 - see http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php

Comment: Interesting Rob. Wasn't aware of this.

Comment: @SparkDesigns: Sure you can, and in this case it's the correct thing to do. But only because `DOMDocument::loadHtml` specifically allows it.

Comment: I get the following error though: Strict Standards: Non-static method DOMDocument::loadHTML() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context

Answer (score 0):

The error actually said it just perfeclly: loadHtml returned a Bool (true/false). Check the manual for the return value.

Error: `Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to DOMXPath::__construct() must be an instance of DOMDocument, boolean given`

Code:

```
$xpath = new DomXPath((new DomDocument())->loadHtml($html));
//                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//                     Argument 1, that returned a bool.
```